# Parse REST API not returning Client Key

Tags: android, rest, parse-platform

I'm trying to create Parse apps on the fly and use the keys while building my Android application. [The API](https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide#apps-creating-apps) works great except for one point, it does not return the `Client Key`.

```
{
"appName": "my new app",
"dashboardURL": "https://www.parse.com/apps/my-new-app--30",
"applicationId": "oQqMyipkIgxYFXRROYTZsREfTcXp770awB1yMVrs",
"javascriptKey": "XAPZ7DoZHQIhMC8vPqN1m79wRIQyIXv7tmVIHmRs",
"windowsKey": "ZsyfFr0WtaQx6tsCokNSmTvjd05QCbCbMLzpChvP",
"webhookKey": "LyXnWJ3tRH56gK19KC1fjTvoUbdSUZoXhyO6khoT",
"restKey": "dzpdzYNkts2xZxPDVe7qC298Z20oIXhLJAPuY2Dw",
"masterKey": "0M2uUDZdKa1KYC1VBrmDaGK3chBaUMw0c2M4XXw1",
"clientPushEnabled": true,
"clientClassCreationEnabled": true,
"requireRevocableSessions": true,
"revokeSessionOnPasswordChange": true
}
```

And I need the client key as mentioned in the Android API:

```
Parse.initialize(this, "YOUR_APP_ID", "YOUR_CLIENT_KEY");
```

I have tried toggling the flags in vain.

What should I do inorder to access the `Client Key`?

**Edit:**

I'm talking about the `Client Key` which appears here: http://postimg.org/image/f76lj6xcr/

Comment: does that define a new client, or is it still the same client? (in which case the client key is the same)

Comment: It is for the same client. I'm not using Parse Objects, I'm just using the Create + Push API.

Comment: then you probably already have the client key?

Comment: Let me explain again. I'm creating a new app and their REST API returns the JSON mentioned in my question. I don't have the Client Key as the Parse App is newly created.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'client'. I am creating a new Parse App. Please refer this: https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide#apps-creating-apps

Comment: I think @njzk2 got it all right. Try to use the new keys and the client key you had in a new Android application to confirm. application != client (here, client seems the same)

Comment: to be clear: when you create an app, you receive the javascript key, which is used for calls from a JS client, and the windows key, which is used for calls from a heavy client, but not the clientkey, which is used for calls from a mobile app (that's a crappy name, it is totally confusing)

Comment: if you go to the dashboard, you should see the app created, and possibly the client keys. can you make sure these are different?

Comment: No, that is not what I'm trying to ask. Say I am building 10 apps each with a different `App Id` and `Client Key`. For this, I'm creating new Parse Apps and using the keys I get from them in the Android applications. I'm not regenerating the keys.

Comment: @njzk2 The new Parse App is created fine with unique keys and I can see it in the admin panel. But, when I create it using the REST API, the API does not return the `Client Key`. I need that key to build my app on-the-fly, going to the admin panel will require manual intervention.

Comment: The client key does not have to change (still a Android client). A new application only means a new application key. Check by code and/or dashboard as suggested.

Comment: I'm talking about the client key which appears here:
http://postimg.org/image/f76lj6xcr/

And it changes for every Android application I build.

Comment: It would indeed appear that parse returns a bunch of keys, but not the mobile key. (but why on earth is it called `Client Key`? that's beyond me.) Have you tried asking parse directly?

Comment: Thank god we are now on the same page and you understood my question. I have posted in their Google forum. Awaiting someone's response there as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a minor bug in the Parse REST API. They fixed it within 48 hours after reporting.